# Multi-Row Function

Tags: oracle, plsql

How to return a multi-row data from a function with cursor ?

```
Create or Replace function  Get_Course_details(Stud_ID number)
  return varchar2
Is

    cursor C_1 is
      select d.desc_english
        from course_details d ,course_track c , students s
       where D.COURSE_TRACK_ID = C.COURSE_TRACK_ID
         and C.COURSE_TRACK_ID = s.STUDENT_ID
         and s.student_ID=stud_ID;
    cursor C_2 is
      select count(d.desc_english)
        from course_details d ,course_track c , students s
       where D.COURSE_TRACK_ID = C.COURSE_TRACK_ID
         and C.COURSE_TRACK_ID = s.STUDENT_ID
         and s.student_ID=stud_ID;
  var_1   varchar2(1000);
  var_2 number;
Begin
  open c_2;
  fetch c_2
    into var_2;
  close c_2;
  for x in (select d.desc_english
              from course_details d ,course_track c , students s
             where D.COURSE_TRACK_ID = C.COURSE_TRACK_ID
               and C.COURSE_TRACK_ID = s.STUDENT_ID
               and s.student_ID=stud_ID)
  loop
    open c_1;
    fetch c_1
    into var_1;
    close c_1;
    return var_1;
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: I don't understand the question.  If you are trying to return a cursor, declare your function to return a `sys_refcursor`.  I'm having trouble following your code since you're mixing explicit and implicit cursors, your implicit cursor driving the `x` loop appears to be identical to the explicit cursor `c_1` and it's not clear what you are trying to accomplish.  Maybe you want to create a pipelined table function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so as Justin pointed out there are few issues with your current function:

1. `var_2` is never used.
2. You are trying to return multirow data, however, the function will return `var_1` to the calling procedure on the very first iteration.

The below solution assumes you are trying to get an array of strings from a cursor that returns many rows. It is a generic demonstration, you will have modify it for you particular instance.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION string_array_from_cursor
RETURN dbms_sql.Varchar2_Table
  IS

  --Obviously this could be _ANY_ select query
  CURSOR cursorToReturnManyRows IS
  SELECT o.object_name
  FROM   user_objects o
  WHERE  o.OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE';

  --This is an inbuilt index-by table (you could also use a varray,
  --  associative array or nested table)
  stringArray dbms_sql.Varchar2_Table;

BEGIN

  --Use a FOR loop to iterate through the cursor, 
  -- at each iteration add the value as the next item in the array 
  FOR rec IN cursorToReturnManyRows LOOP
    stringArray(stringArray.count + 1) := rec.object_name;
  END LOOP;

  --After the loop is complete return the array
  RETURN stringArray;

END;
```

I suggest you compile the above function, and run it the below test window to see how it can apply to your instance.

```
DECLARE

  stringArray dbms_sql.Varchar2_Table;

BEGIN

  stringArray := string_array_from_cursor;

  dbms_output.put_line(stringArray.count);

  FOR i IN 1..stringArray.count LOOP
   dbms_output.put_line(stringArray(i));
  END LOOP;

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can return an opened SYS_REFCURSOR and let the caller fetch from the cursor:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_COURSE_DETAIL_CURSOR(STUD_ID NUMBER)
  RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
IS
  C_1  SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  OPEN C_1 FOR SELECT d.DESC_ENGLISH
                 FROM STUDENTS s 
                 INNER JOIN COURSE_TRACK c
                   ON c.COURSE_TRACK_ID = s.STUDENT_ID
                 INNER JOIN COURSE_DETAILS d
                   ON d.COURSE_TRACK_ID = c.COURSE_TRACK_ID
                 WHERE S.STUDENT_ID = STUD_ID;

  RETURN C_1;
END GET_COURSE_DETAIL_CURSOR;
```

The caller would, of course, be responsible for closing the cursor.

(And BTW - the join criteria `c.COURSE_TRACK_ID = s.STUDENT_ID` seems to be contradictory with the later join criteria `d.COURSE_TRACK_ID = c.COURSE_TRACK_ID`, but on the other hand I don't know your data. It just looks odd to me).

Share and enjoy.